# ArrayList<String> parse into recyclerview with retrofit android

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Hello I have a one `JSON` but it is an Array of `ArrayList<String>` i have confusion about this type of array How can i Parse these type of array into my `recyclerview` using `Retrofit`.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "success": true,
  "message": "Data get succesfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "attributes_id": 20,
      "category_id": "3",
      "subcategory_id": "13",
      "product_id": "28",
      "attribute_name": "Make",
      "isRequired": "yes",
      "attribute_type": "dropdown",
      "attribute_options": [
        "LG",
        "Samsung",
        "Kelvinetor",
        "Haier",
        "Wrilphool",
        "Other"
      ],
      "created_at": "2019-07-01 12:02:18",
      "updated_at": "2019-07-01 12:02:57"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my `json` and i try to **attribute_options** list into `Recyclerview`.
Help me out.

This is my response:

```
public class GetAttributesResponse {

@SerializedName("statusCode")
@Expose
private int statusCode;

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private boolean success;

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private ArrayList<DataClass> dataclass = null;

public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public ArrayList<DataClass> getDataclass() {
    return dataclass;
}

public void setDataclass(ArrayList<DataClass> dataclass) {
    this.dataclass = dataclass;
}

public class DataClass {

    @SerializedName("attributes_id")
    @Expose
    private int attributes_id;

    @SerializedName("category_id")
    @Expose
    private String category_id;

    @SerializedName("subcategory_id")
    @Expose
    private String subcategory_id;

    @SerializedName("product_id")
    @Expose
    private String product_id;

    @SerializedName("attribute_name")
    @Expose
    private String attribute_name;

    @SerializedName("isRequired")
    @Expose
    private String isRequired;

    @SerializedName("attribute_type")
    @Expose
    private String attribute_type;

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String created_at;

    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updated_at;

    @SerializedName("attribute_options")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> attribute_options = null;

    public int getAttributes_id() {
        return attributes_id;
    }

    public void setAttributes_id(int attributes_id) {
        this.attributes_id = attributes_id;
    }

    public String getCategory_id() {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setCategory_id(String category_id) {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    public String getSubcategory_id() {
        return subcategory_id;
    }

    public void setSubcategory_id(String subcategory_id) {
        this.subcategory_id = subcategory_id;
    }

    public String getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(String product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public String getAttribute_name() {
        return attribute_name;
    }

    public void setAttribute_name(String attribute_name) {
        this.attribute_name = attribute_name;
    }

    public String getIsRequired() {
        return isRequired;
    }

    public void setIsRequired(String isRequired) {
        this.isRequired = isRequired;
    }

    public String getAttribute_type() {
        return attribute_type;
    }

    public void setAttribute_type(String attribute_type) {
        this.attribute_type = attribute_type;
    }

    public String getCreated_at() {
        return created_at;
    }

    public void setCreated_at(String created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public String getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(String updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAttribute_options() {
        return attribute_options;
    }

    public void setAttribute_options(ArrayList<String> attribute_options) {
        this.attribute_options = attribute_options;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please add your retrofit code where you have received the json data.

Comment: Have you made model class for using with retrofit

Comment: @Antonio Please check out i update my question and add My Response

Comment: @UmarHussain i added My Response Code please check out.

Comment: @HitechP, can you show the code where you are receiving the response?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the JSON to POJO classes using [Class Generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

```
package com.test.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {

@SerializedName("attributes_id")
@Expose
private Integer attributesId;
@SerializedName("category_id")
@Expose
private String categoryId;
@SerializedName("subcategory_id")
@Expose
private String subcategoryId;
@SerializedName("product_id")
@Expose
private String productId;
@SerializedName("attribute_name")
@Expose
private String attributeName;
@SerializedName("isRequired")
@Expose
private String isRequired;
@SerializedName("attribute_type")
@Expose
private String attributeType;
@SerializedName("attribute_options")
@Expose
private List<String> attributeOptions = null;
@SerializedName("created_at")
@Expose
private String createdAt;
@SerializedName("updated_at")
@Expose
private String updatedAt;

public Integer getAttributesId() {
return attributesId;
}

public void setAttributesId(Integer attributesId) {
this.attributesId = attributesId;
}

public String getCategoryId() {
return categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getSubcategoryId() {
return subcategoryId;
}

public void setSubcategoryId(String subcategoryId) {
this.subcategoryId = subcategoryId;
}

public String getProductId() {
return productId;
}

public void setProductId(String productId) {
this.productId = productId;
}

public String getAttributeName() {
return attributeName;
}

public void setAttributeName(String attributeName) {
this.attributeName = attributeName;
}

public String getIsRequired() {
return isRequired;
}

public void setIsRequired(String isRequired) {
this.isRequired = isRequired;
}

public String getAttributeType() {
return attributeType;
}

public void setAttributeType(String attributeType) {
this.attributeType = attributeType;
}

public List<String> getAttributeOptions() {
return attributeOptions;
}

public void setAttributeOptions(List<String> attributeOptions) {
this.attributeOptions = attributeOptions;
}

public String getCreatedAt() {
return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUpdatedAt() {
return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

}

package com.test.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class FeasibilityModel {

@SerializedName("statusCode")
@Expose
private Integer statusCode;
@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private Boolean success;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public Boolean getSuccess() {
return success;
}

public void setSuccess(Boolean success) {
this.success = success;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

Retrofit Example

```
 @GET("//Your End Point URL")
    Call<Datum> getList();
```

Your Response example

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Hero>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Datum> call, Response<Datum> response) {

                //In this point we got our hero list
                //thats damn easy right ;) 

//now we can do whatever we want with this list

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Datum> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Reference Link : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-example/

Comment: Thanks for your replay , but here i have only Array key not a perticuler value vise data